# PowerShell: Multiple Conditions within IF Statement

Tags: powershell

Im struggling to understand why the following IF statement doesn't work...

I have a PS array:

```
$lunchArray = @('Pizza', 'Sushi', 'Sandwich')
```

However the following Foreach/IF statement doesn't work as expected.

```
foreach ($lunch in $lunchArray) {
    if ($lunch -eq 'Pizza' -and $lunch -eq 'Sushi') {
        "YAY" # not working...
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

TIA

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? You're doing an and on a single value. How on earth should lunch ever be Pizza and Sushi?

Comment: You're saying if it equals both. `-or` to compare it against those 2. There are other operators you can use such as `-contains`, and `-in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lunchArray = @('Pizza', 'Sushi', 'Sandwich')

foreach ($lunch in $lunchArray) {
    if ('Pizza' -eq $lunch -or 'Sushi' -eq $lunch) {
        "YAY" # not working...
    }
}
```

Comment: `-in` is the wrong operator for what you're comparing. It will work but is not the correct one, `-eq` was fine.